# CSS transform-origin moving origin the wrong way

Tags: jquery, css

I was attempting to animate the menu bar on my html page. The approach I took was splitting it in to two seperate divs, translating the origin of the divs to the center of the page and then scaling the divs' x value to 0. The code of the html and css is below:

```css
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    
    body {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-image: url(html-bg2.png);
    background-size: 0.5%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-color: #111111;
    overflow: auto;
    }
    
    #headbar_left {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    width: 51vw;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #161616;
    border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
    transition: all 0.65s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 0% -50%;
    }
    
    #headbar_right {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    width: 51vw;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #161616;
    border-bottom: 1vh solid #8704ff;
    transition: all 0.65s ease-in-out;
    transform-origin: 0% 50%;
    }
    
    #circle_logo {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 17vh;
    height: 17vh;
    border-radius: 8.5vh;
    background-color: #161616;
    left: calc(50vw - 8.5vh);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1vh solid #8704ff;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 17vh;
    font-size: 7em;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
    transition: all 0.65s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    #logo {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
    transition: inherit;
    }
    
    .spin {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    
    .collapse {
    transform: scaleX(0);
    }
    
    #body_content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 86vw;
    height: 105vh;
    margin-right: 7vw;
    margin-left: 7vw;
    margin-top: 10vh;
    background-color: #161616;
    z-index: -1;
    box-shadow: 0px 3vh 10vh 4vh black;
    }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="uh.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>uh</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="headbar_left"></div>
    <div id="headbar_right"></div>
    <div id="circle_logo"><img src="html-logo.png" id="logo"></div>
    <div id="body_content"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
    $(document).scroll(function()
    { 
       if($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
         $("#circle_logo").addClass('spin');
         $("#headbar_left").addClass('collapse');
         $("#headbar_right").addClass('collapse');
       }
       else {
         $("#circle_logo").removeClass('spin');
         $("#headbar_left").removeClass('collapse');
         $("#headbar_right").removeClass('collapse');
       } 
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

The problem is that when the divs that make up the menu bar collapse, the right one collapses into the center like I want it to, but the left one collapses to the left of the page. I translated the origin for the right one 50% and -50% for the left one, but it seems as though they have both just been translated 50%. Any idea how I can fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to make a simple change?

```
#headbar_left
{
    transform-origin: 100% -50%;
}
```

BTW if you are saying that a value is 0 you don't have to define px or any other unit of measure as it is just 0 no matter what unit of measure you use.

I am "NOT" a super uber scripting champ but I can at least see you could reduce your jQuery snippet a tiny bit by combining the two elements with ,

```
$(document).scroll(function()
{ 
   if($(window).scrollTop() !== 0) {
     $("#circle_logo").addClass('spin');
     $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").addClass('collapse');
   }
   else {
     $("#circle_logo").removeClass('spin');
     $("#headbar_left, #headbar_right").removeClass('collapse');
   } 
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly! And thanks for the jQuery advice, I'm quite new to it so I don't know any of the shortcuts.

Comment: A super uber scripting champ might have taken advantage of [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) .... `$("#circle_logo").toggleClass('spin', ($(window).scrollTop() !== 0);`

Comment: That is funny I meant to say "NOT" super uber scripting champ!
@JonP  we will call on you nest time buddy! Hehe.

Comment: OK Coolio! It honestly came out totally the wrong way by omitting the keyword 'not'. Lel.

Comment: I tried using toggleClass like you suggested, Jon, but it doesn't do anything, probably because I screwed up the implementation. Here's my code:
`$(document).scroll(function() {
$("#circle_logo").toggleClass('spin', ($(window).scrollTop() !== 0);
});`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that I was just missing a parenthese at the end.